# How to reset MSMQ permissions after changing domains

Tags: msmq

What considerations should be addressed when moving a Microsoft 2003 server with MSMQ installed to another domain?

We assigned permissions to the queue for a user account from the new domain. We still get an error "Access to Message Queing system is denied."

There are no other servers in the new domain running MSMQ.  Is there an Active Directory object that gets created when MSMQ is installed on a member server?

Comment: Do you mean the machine on which MSMQ was installed was moved to another domain?

Comment: Yes.  We actually had to remove the server from the domain, rebuild a new domain, then rejoin the server to the new domain.  We removed the orphaned user object in the permissions list and added a user from the new domain.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been resolved.  The problem was with a private queue created by our application.  That explains why we didn't see any AD object created.  Using domain admin credentials, we tried to modify the permissions on the private queue using the MMC snapin. We got an error and could not make the required change because the domain admin was not on the ACL for that queue.  We found a work around to the problem.  We created a new temporary private queue and assigned full control to the user account we need for our application.  We located the newly created private queue configuration file in the \system32\msmq\storage\lqs directory.  We opened the file and copied the entire security line.  Then we opened the configuration file for the private queue we are trying to fix and pasted the security line over the same line in that file.  We saved the configuration file.  We restarted the MSMQ service and then started our application service.  The application could now function properly.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the domain is in a different forest and you wish to make use of public queues, etc. then you will need to reinstall MSMQ so that all the MSMQ objects are created in AD.

What exact operation generates "Access to Message Queing system is denied."?

Comment: A component of our software throws the error message embedded with additional information. We do not use public queues and we don't see any objects created in AD for MSMQ. Another post mentioned the AD objects and that confused the issue. I believe we found a method to resolve the problem.  We will post the steps taken.

Comment: I thought you mentioned AD objects in the original question "Is there an Active Directory object that gets created when MSMQ is installed on a member server?"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any messages or journal history that you need to save, I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling MSMQ.

Have you logged into the server directly using the account that is trying to send the message? This is necessary to establish a message queuing certificate, a little understood and poorly documented area of MSMQ.

Comment: Thanks!  We will try that.  I don't think we ever logged in to the server console using that account.

Answer (score 0):

We also found another easier way to reset the permissions on the private queue.  Instead of modifying the private queue configuration file, we took ownership of the private queue as the domain admin, assigned full permissions to the user account needed for our application, and transfered ownership to the same user.  This restored the private queue to the state it was in prior to the server move.

Comment: It would be best to merge this and the other answer you posted into a _single_ answer, and mark the final version accepted, so that it will be obvious to future visitors what the resolution was. Don't overlook the `edit` link under the questions and answers.